# Assignment - Finding nearest point on a plane. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an assignment i'm working on and i a little stuck.. I think I'm on the right path, but this keeps returning undefined.

*EDIT: the goal is to pass in an array of two points and find witch in the source array is closer.*

Any guidance with some explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2 - y2, 2));
}

function minimumDistance(inputArray, destArray) {
    let inputX = inputArray.x;
    let inputY = inputArray.y;
    let minDistance = calcDistance(inputX, inputY, destArray[0].x, destArray[0].y)
    let minPoint;

    for (let i = 0; i < destArray.lenght; i++) {
        let distance = calcDistance(inputX, inputY, destArray[i].x, destArray[i].y);
        if (minDistance > distance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            minPoint = i;
        }
        return destArray[minPoint];
    }
}


testData = { x: 0, y: 0 }
sourceArr = [{ x: 100, y: 0 }, { x: 200, y: 10 }]

console.log(minimumDistance(testDatac, sourceArr));
```

Comment: You're missing an actual explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: fyi: [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) makes things easier.

Comment: I advice to use a debugger. It lets you go through your program step-by-step and you can see what the values of all the variables/properties are. It's a pretty useful skill to learn anyway.

Comment: @NinaScholz, could you explain the use in this situation?

Comment: @Ivar just added the chrome debugger to vscode, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Latent-code, this `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2 - y2, 2));` becomes `Math.hypot(x1 - y1, x2 - y2)`, which is shorter and works for multi dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but here are some changes I made:

1. start minDistance at +Infinity and then loop over all the points (alternatively, initialize minPoint on 0 does the same)
2. fix typo lenght => length
3. move return statement to after the loop (so the program can check all points before returning a value)
4. Fix the calcDistance function to use the right formula (`sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2))`

```js
function calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}

function minimumDistance(inputArray, destArray) {
    let inputX = inputArray.x;
    let inputY = inputArray.y;
    let minDistance = +Infinity;
    let minPoint;

    for (let i = 0; i < destArray.length; i++) {
        let distance = calcDistance(inputX, inputY, destArray[i].x, destArray[i].y);
        if (minDistance > distance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            minPoint = i;
        }
    }
    return destArray[minPoint];
}


testSrc = { x: 0, y: 0 }
testArr = [{ x: 100, y: 0 }, { x: 200, y: 10 }]

console.log(minimumDistance(testSrc, testArr));

testSrc = { x: 200, y: 80 }

console.log(minimumDistance(testSrc, testArr));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.. the typo was just annoying. also setting minPoint to 0; actually made the code return something with is good, but:
If you change The following: testSrc = { x: 200, y: 80 }; it should return {x:200, y:10} the closest point in the testArr.. witch this does not.

Comment: It seems your calcdistance function is not returning the right value, I fixed that also

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Could you explain the use of +Infinity in this case?

Comment: It's a cleaner way of initializing the minDistance, since the first iteration of the loop will always find a distance value lower than +Infinity. The advantage is that if your `destArray` has no elements, the function will not crash (because `destArray[0].x` for example will give an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume you want something like this.

```
// Calculate euclidean distance between a and b (which should be objects with x/y properties)
function euclideanDistance(a, b) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2));
}

// Find an object `x` in `otherPoints` that minimizes `metric(point, x)`
function minimumDistance(point, otherPoints, metric) {
  let minDistance, minPoint;
  otherPoints.forEach((otherPoint) => {
    const distance = metric(point, otherPoint);
    if (minDistance === undefined || distance < minDistance) {
      minDistance = distance;
      minPoint = otherPoint;
    }
  });
  return [minPoint, minDistance];
}

testSrc = { x: 0, y: 0 };
testArr = [
  { x: 100, y: 0 },
  { x: 200, y: 10 },
];

console.log(minimumDistance(testSrc, testArr, euclideanDistance));
```

Comment: Basically if you change testSrc = { x: 200, y: 80 }; it should return {x:200, y:10} the closest point.. witch this does not?

Answer (score 0):

You initialize minDistance with the distance the first point has to the inputArray and then compare all other distances to this. This works fine if you also initialize the minPoint to 0.

In the current program you would only enter the ifstatement if your first distance is not the smallest in total.

To fix this: initialize minPoint to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there yes! I fixed some typos and you omitted to default `minPoint` to `0`

```js
function calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}

function minimumDistance(inputObject, destArray) {
    let inputX = inputObject.x;
    let inputY = inputObject.y;
    let minDistance = calcDistance(inputX, inputY, destArray[0].x, destArray[0].y);
    let minPoint = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i < destArray.length; i++) {
        let distance = calcDistance(inputX, inputY, destArray[i].x, destArray[i].y);
        if (minDistance > distance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            minPoint = i;
        }
    }
    return destArray[minPoint];
}

testSrc = { x: 0, y: 0 };
testArr = [{ x: 100, y: 0 }, { x: 200, y: 10 }]

console.log(minimumDistance(testSrc, testArr));
```

Comment: If you change testSrc to a higher number than 150 and 5 it still returns the smaller point from the testArr.. so it doesent work?